# How can i create test for a function that return a collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec-rails

I am implementing a test for a function that return a collection by a query select, this function `select_collection`  want to test with specs, so i am trying to mocking like this

```
let(:scenaries) { [
    double(: organizational_unit, section_id: section.id, type_id: type.id),
    double(: organizational_unit, section_id: section.id, type_id: type.id)
  ] }
```

now i want to test this function comparing scenaries with the result of select_collection

```
 def select_collection
    OrganizationalUnit.where('section.id = ? ...)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't mock objects in that way... an *array* of instance doubles is not the same thing as an object collection, and I don't think your doubles are even being instantiated (you aren't referencing 'scenaries' in your snippets and you're using `let` not `let!` that var is being lazy loaded). There are a few things that would need fixing here.

First, what is the intention behind `select_collection`? The naming sounds like it's selecting the entire collection, but that would be redundant to the built-in `OrganizationalUnit.all` query method. If you're filtering the collection (you do have a `where` in your snippet), then it's best to use a more specific name.

Second, your code snippet is defining `select_collection` as an instance method (`def select_collection`), but your test is calling it as a class method (which would need to be defined as `def self.select_collection`). But if all you want to do is return a filtered collection of objects from that model, you should define it as a query scope (*not* a class/instance method): https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

Third,  you're testing querying objects, you should be creating them as actual test objects and writing a test that looks something like this:

```rb
describe '.some_scope_name' do
  subject(:result) { OrganizationalUnit.some_scope_name }

  let!(:expected_units) { 
    create_list :organizational_unit, 3,
      some_attribute: true
  }
  let!(:excluded) { 
    create :organizational_unit, 
      some_attribute: false

  it 'fetches expected collection' do
    expect(result).to contain_exactly(expected_units)
  end
end
```

Using a `let!` ensures the objects exist in our test DB before we trigger the query in our example.

Recommend reading:

- https://www.betterspecs.org/
- https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations#collection-membership